# returning the largest odd number from a list none if no odd exist

Tags: python, list

here's the question, homework what I follow there after,not correct.

def largest_odd_times(L):
        """ Assumes L is a non-empty list of ints
            Returns the largest element of L that occurs an odd number 
            of times in L. If no such element exists, returns None """

```
    # Your code here
```

For example, if 
• largest_odd_times([2,2,4,4]) returns None
• largest_odd_times([3,9,5,3,5,3]) returns 9

```
from collections import Counter
        L = [3, 3, 2, 0, 9]
        def largest_odd_times(L):
            """ Assumes L is a non-empty list of ints
                Returns the largest element of L that occurs an odd number 
                of times in L. If no such element exists, returns None """
            L.sort(reverse=True)
            counted = Counter(L).items()
            for x in counted:
                if x[1] % 2 == 1:
                    return x[0]
            return None


    Test: largest_odd_times([3, 2])
    my output:2, correct output 3
    Test: largest_odd_times([3, 3, 2, 0])
    myoutput,0 correct output 2 
    Test: largest_odd_times([6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8])
    My output, none, correct output 8
    Test: largest_odd_times([2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2])
    my output 5, correct 4

    What wrong in this code, explanation of  where I went wrong and what should have done and fixing will be really great.
    Thank you.
```

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest the OP is looking for the largest value that occurs an odd number of times in the list, not necessarily an odd number itself.

Comment: Thank you guys for the working.
Couldn't just get my head around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler method:

```
from collections import Counter

def largest_odd_times(l):

    d = Counter(l)

    #d now stores: {8: 5, 6: 5}

    numbers = [a for a, b in d.items() if b%2 != 0]

    if len(numbers) > 0:
       return max(numbers)

    else:
       return None


print(largest_odd_times([6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8, 6, 8]))
```

Output:

```
8
```

Comment: Thank you Ajax1234,
Your answer helps,however I am having just a little trouble understanding the first line after the function is defined,could you please try and explain what it doing?
I figure some,but not all.
Thank you.

Comment: @raven_richard the counter method will return a dictionary that stores each element in the list passed to the function as a key and the number of times the value occurs in the list. Please see my recent edit for the contents of what the Counter method returns.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a concise list comprehension can accomplish what you want. The list comprehension actually returns a tuple containing the number of occurrences, followed by the number that had the highest odd number of occurrences in the list.

```
a = [2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]
r = max([(a.count(v),v) for v in a if a.count(v) % 2])[1]
print(r)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what I did

def largest_odd_times(L):
    '''
    L is list, returns largest element of L that occurs an odd # of times
    '''

```
try:
    m = max(L) #finds largest element in list

except ValueError: # if there is none (eg. empty list)
    return None
count = L.count(m)  # how many times does the max element occur

if count%2 == 1 :  # check if its odd
    return m
else:
    L = [x for x in L if x != m]  # if it's not odd, remove all instances
    return largest_odd_times(L)
```